# Create an instance of a component with CLSID COM's {...} from IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a01ad

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I have a classLibrary project written in c#.
I have an old dll (cares managing data in db) that my project reference to.
when I try to create object of class from that dll, I get error:

**Create an instance of a component with CLSID COM's {...} from IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a01ad.**

what I tried:
1. execute regsvr32 command from cmd - got success but it still does not work.
2. using regAsm command to register the dll - got success but it still does not work.

the target framework is framework 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The factory has problems to create the com object.
In most cases there are missing dll's, which need to be loaded when the object is created.

Is that COM server implemented in C# or is it a native COM server?
If it's dotnet, you can use [fuslogvw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501422/sidebyside-registration-free-com-fail-while-loading) for finding the missing assembly.
If not, take a dll dependency walker.